# JavaScript behavior and code check

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bi4BR1UvYx5WIcvN99t0?p=preview).

The gist is this code:

```
var myObj = function (){
  return {
    getThis: function (callback) {
      return callback("this");
    }
  }
}

var myDidSome = function () {
  return {
    DoSome: function (text) {
      return text + " is cool";
    }
  };
};

var subObj = function (objG, didSome) {
  var txt = objG.getThis(function (text) {
    return didSome.DoSome(text);
  });

  console.log(txt);
}

new subObj(new myObj, new myDidSome);
```

So to deconstruct this code, view `myObj` and `myDidSome` as services (*angular ones*). I'm most interested in the `myObj.getThis`, this is supposed to mimick some `$http` response. So when its finished call my `callback` function passing in the parameters obtained from `$http`.

The thing I keep thinking about though is `$http` is `async`. Will my `txt` property in the `subOj` (*think of this as a controller*) class be populated correctly when the data gets back, I assume it will be `undefined` till then?

In my scenario this is completely synchronous, which obviously works.

So, I would like to know whether `async` will be an issue here? And whether doing this practice of propagating the `return` of an object is a good one, or doesn't matter, or is bad and I shouldn't do it?

Comment: It will not work when it is async. Test it out by adding a setTimeout in there to act like it is getting the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `return` like that with an asynchronous method. You have to do everything within the callback. In your example, the result of `didSome.DoSome(text)` will never be assigned to `txt`, not even after the callback has run.

For a simple case like this where you're logging the response, doing it in the callback is an acceptable approach. If you need to do something more complex, however, you should look into [promises via `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). These provide a much nicer way to rewrite a long chain of callbacks into a more linear flow.